# Scroll less then default when clicked navitem

Tags: javascript, html

I have navbar with items. When i click on item it scrolls me down to the div. For example i click on contact and it scrolls me to contact. My problem is that i have fixed navbar. And my navbar hide heading of section. So when i click on contact it scrolls me down to contact but heading is behind navbar.

This is my script i need to add something like  scroll - 55px or something like that but i dont know how.

```
<script>
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first check if link clicked is `/contact` and then apply a different scroll like this:

```
if (target.length) {
    // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
    event.preventDefault();

    let scrollOffset = 0;
    if ($(this).attr('href') === '/contact') {
     scrollOffset = 55;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top + scrollOffset
    }, 1000, function() {
      // Callback after animation
      // Must change focus!
      var $target = $(target);
      $target.focus();
      if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
        return false;
      } else {
        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
      };
    });
  }
```

It's not the most elegant solution but that should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad if it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you could share html as well it would be easy to understand. Anyways, as i understood the problem is with fixed navbar. When Positioning absolute/fixed is used the div is then out of the flow of the document. To get elements start immediately after header you would need to give elements container a margin-top equal to the height of the header. This is the easiest solution. You do not need to do anything with js.